# To set the maximum length to Text Area in ASP

Tags: asp.net, javascript

What's the best way of restricting the maximum number of characters that can be entered into an asp textarea?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have to count the number of text entered in a text area and limit the text if the length(text entered) reaches maximum.

Eg. of Javascript can be found here: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-3"><asp:TextBox ID="TbxUserName" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control intxt" placeholder="Enter User Name" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox></div>
```